# ImageMagick - Add Transparent / Semi Transparent text watermark on Image

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to create resized, lower quality image with transparent/semi transparent WHITE txt watermark.
As i`m not imagemagic expert i already do my researches and get to point of following command:

`magick.exe "C:\Test\Test.tif" -resize 800x -quality 60% -set 'option:size' '%[fx:w*0.5]x%[fx:h*0.5]' -pointsize 285 -font Arial -background none -fill rgba(255,255,255,0.5) -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TEST" "C:\Test\Test1.Tiff"`

I have made test on like 10 different source images, with different orientation, colour, black&white etc. Is working fine for almost all of them. Unfortunetly it needs to work for all not "almost all".
In some cases resize, watermark position is all good, however... watermark is transparent grey instead of white...
Thought issue is with background but even if set it to white, same thing.
Hitting wall with that atm, would massivly appreciate any help.
Attaching excample output that i`m looking for[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSz3X.jpg)

As per description, played with RGB codes, (check many different configs for it with same results)
Tried reorganise order of params as read is also important, but without luck as well.
Checked different commands as well but one that i`ve paste here is what i need, despite issue with txt colour.

Comment: It's hard to know what the real problem is or how to answer you. Please add a starting image and result that work, then add a starting image and result that doesn't work. Then show the command you used.

Comment: Hi Mark, agreed. Was not much clear on my question, but discover root cause of my issue. My Watermark colour depends on source image colour space. So if source file got CMYK colour space set text colour rgba(255,255,255,0.5) ends with grey colour of watermark instead of white, when set colour rgba(0,0,0,0.5) then end with white colour of watermark. My problem is that i got hundreds of thousands images in system with different colour spaces and need generic command that will handle to give me white watermark as output. found partly solution with adding param "-colorspace CMYK" and set water...

Comment: ...Watermark colour with rgba(0,0,0,0.5) so that give me output for all tested files with white semi transparent watermark, problem is that all outputs that have RGB, YUV colour space, are a bit brighter. Can in my codes dynamic profile depends of source colour space, but as mentioned above, i am not an expert in that area so cannot be 100% sure if i will cover all cases.
Unfortunately i`m unable to share my example images as they got copyrights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that as follows in Imagemagick. Create a black image with your text the same size as the input. Then compose plus with the input.

IM 7 Unix syntax:

Input:

[image]

```
magick lena.jpg \
\( +clone -fill black -colorize 100 \
-fill "gray(35%)" -gravity center -font arial-bold -pointsize 64 -annotate +0+0 "TEXT" \) \
-compose plus -composite \
lena_text.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Hi fmw42, much appreciate your response.  Test it similar code already, as per my respone to Mark above, issue is due to source color space.  So as above is working fine for RGB, YUV, in case when source image got CMYK colour space , watermark become transparent grey.

Comment: Check your input colorspace and convert to RGB before watermarking.  Imagemagick generally expects most processing to be done in RGB colorspace. IM colors may be specified in several color spaces including CMYK, but then they are internally converted to RGB(A).

Comment: Hey fmw42. Checked playing with colorspace before watermarking and it`s change colorspace of picture that my RGP pictures become negatives. 
Closest "generic" command i`ve found is
"source file" -resize 800x -quality 60% -set 'option:size' '%[fx:w*0.5]x%[fx:h*0.5]' -pointsize 285 -font Arial -background transparent -colorspace CMYK -fill rgba(0,0,0,0.5) -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Test" "output".
Again much appreciate your advises mate, and all best :)

Comment: Hey fmw42. i have finished with:
"source_file" -resize 800x -quality 60% -set 'option:size' '%[fx:w*0.5]x%[fx:h*0.5]' -pointsize 285 -font Candara -background transparent -colorspace CMYK -fill rgba(0,0,0,0.5) -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "watermark" "output"
That is give me wanted output for all file types with any source color space. Know is not ideal but still best what found.
Had of course .net validation problems for tif files but that is different story:)
Again appreciate your help and best regards